# Google Directions API - can you query for directions with waypoints and alternatives set to true

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

Is it possible to get alternate routes from point A to point B which goes through C, D and E? If I set waypoints I can't see any alternate routes.

Also how reliable is google directions API? When I don't give waypoints and ask for alternatives, I get routes going on top of lakes and parks.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone has any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update after playing around with google directions API - the alternate routes are working fine. I missed backspace and that caused the issue when trying to use the encoded overview_polyline points on google map. This actually resulted in polylines going over parks.